# Moving a far right float from the right margin

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a navbar that has 5 elements nicely floated to the left. I then add an element that I want to be on the far right, but I want a little bit of a margin between the element floated to the far right and the edge of the actual document. If I just do `float:right;`, the element is smashed to the end of the document. If I try to mess with `position-right` or `margin-right`, nothing happens. How do I get the element away from the edge?

Comment: What on Earth is `position-right`? If you float the elements left or right, you need to clear them. `margin-right` should be the right one to detach it from the edge.

Comment: Instead of "Let's say", how about you post some code?

Answer (score 4):

A couple options, first use a wrapper to to control the two divs seperation:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left">Left Div</div>
<div id="right">Right Div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wDjFV/

Another option is to do `float: left` on BOTH `<div>`s and seperate with margins there:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left Div</div>
<div id="right">Right Div</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wDjFV/3/

Update:

Just a thought on the second option that you may not know, you'll want to to do `clear:both` on a CSS rule for any `<div>`s that are bellow the ones you are floating to get the normal stacking behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`padding-right` may be what you are looking for, not `position-right`. Either way, `margin-right` should be working to pull the box away from the edge of the page. `padding-right` will keep the box on the edge of the page, but move the containing content further away from the edge.